# What is wrong in my code of custom tab of buddypress?

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, buddypress

Good day!
I am looking for a way to solve that a user who doesn´t have the "shop_manager" role doesn´t appear the custom tab "searches" in his profile.
But the other roles can see it.
Could you help me?

````
function bpcodex_remove_member_tab_on_role() {
  $role = 'shop_manager';
  if ( 'shop_manager' != $role ) {
    bp_core_remove_nav_item( 'busqueda' ); //name of slug 

  }
}
add_action( 'bp_actions', 'bpcodex_remove_member_tab_on_role' );```
````

Comment: Your question is confusing.  Do you mean that the custom tab only appears on profiles for users who have the shop_manger role?  Or is it specific to who is viewing a particular profile?  Either way, your code needs to retrieve the roles for the user in question and then check for the shop_manager role.  Or, even better, add the conditional to the code that creates the tab rather than create it and then maybe remove it.

Comment: thanks but how i can do it? `function child_bp_nav_adder() {
global $bp;
$post_count = count_user_posts_by_type( $bp->displayed_user->id );
bp_core_new_nav_item(
array(
'name' => sprintf( __( 'Búsqueda <span>%d</span>', 'my-poems' ), $post_count ),
'slug' => 'busqueda',
'position' => 250,
'show_for_displayed_user' => true,
'screen_function' => 'child_list',
'default_subnav_slug' => 'public',

));
}`

Comment: Adjust this value as needed:  'show_for_displayed_user' => true,

Comment: Edit your question or ask a new one with your nav_adder code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if ( 'shop_manager' != $role )` should be: `if ( $role != 'shop_manager' )` and if `busqueda`  is a sub-nav item you have to use `bp_core_remove_subnav_item()` instead of `bp_core_remove_nav_item()`

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. This code go on hide the tab for all user including the "shop_manager" role. any sugggest?

Comment: My answer is what I am suggesting,